# How to remove controller name in URL when using URL helpers (Rails 4.2.1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I use this tutorial as the base (Railscasts - Model name in url, 5:30) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=963wTp9FCn4

I've added:

```
resources :points, path: "", only: [:show]
```

and now I can access the page by `/page-name` only when I access it directly. When `point_path(point)` or just `point` is used in one of my views it takes me to the same `/points/page-name`. So in Rails 4 I also have to modify my resourceful URL helpers?

edit: rake routes:

`Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                Controller#Action
import_points POST   /points/import(.:format)   points#import
       points GET    /points(.:format)          points#index
              POST   /points(.:format)          points#create
    new_point GET    /points/new(.:format)      points#new
   edit_point GET    /points/:id/edit(.:format) points#edit
        point GET    /points/:id(.:format)      points#show
              PATCH  /points/:id(.:format)      points#update
              PUT    /points/:id(.:format)      points#update
              DELETE /points/:id(.:format)      points#destroy
         root GET    /                          static_pages#home
      contact GET    /contact(.:format)         static_pages#contact
    portfolio GET    /portfolio(.:format)       static_pages#portfolio
        about GET    /about(.:format)           static_pages#about
        login GET    /login(.:format)           sessions#new
              POST   /login(.:format)           sessions#create
       logout GET    /logout(.:format)          sessions#destroy
         test GET    /test(.:format)            static_pages#test
              GET    /:id(.:format)             points#show`

edit2:
I have checked `resources :points, path: "", only: [:show]` route on another ROR installation and it works, with IDs.
I am using friendly_id gem and the route matches :id instead of my slugged name.

edit3: If I create slugs "manually" like in tutorial everything's working like intended.

edit4: if I put `resources :points, path: "", only: [:show]` on the top of the routes file `point`helper gives me right paths, but my static routes are broken.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So all of those routes are taking you to the right page and you want what to happen?  Sorry I'm not sure I follow.

Comment: Post output of `rake routes`

Comment: @BrianKunzig OP wants to show always `/page-name` as an url path..

Comment: @lac I am getting correct path as per your route definition `app.point_path(1)`.. is giving me `"/1"`..

Comment: @BrianKunzig they are taking me to /points/page-name. If I type /page-name in address line it takes me to /page-name.

Comment: And I want exact the same behavior from my helper(point here)  @RAJ see edit. Arup Rakshit that is correct. Thanks

Comment: @lacerda Update `resources :points` to `resources :points, :except => :show` in your route.rb

Comment: @RAJ it makes no difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
resources :points, path: "", as: 'direct_points', only: [:show]
```

This will give you

```
direct_point_path(point)
```

Which is what you want... it will resolve to (application)/(page_name)

Comment: Thank You sir, it did the trick. Didn't think to use both path: and as:

Comment: But doing this then removes all of the other routes. edit_page_path, new_page_path, page_path...they're all gone. The only routes I have now are: direct_page GET  /:id(.:format) pages#show
       root GET  /              pages#index

Comment: @KyleK so add another resources entry beneath it, with the paths that you need.  You can mix and match.